# Can you build your own villages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you build houses in Minecraft that villagers will detect as villages?I mean building a village from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can.Villagers will detect doors with air blocks(at least 5×5 x-z) as houses,that,if not near other villages,will be detected as villages.You can know that by hitting a villager near or in that house(angry particles will appear,meaning popularity loss).If you hit the villager further away,no particles will appear,meaning that he is not part of a village.This thing can be done easy enough by curing a zombie villager inside or near the house.Then,you can extend the village by the same method or by breeding.This also works on destroyed vilages.If you want to see more about curing zombies, [click here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/zombie) and see Zombie Villager.